# How to make a php script accessible from multiple ips on centos?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, ip, lamp, scripting

I have a php script script which should be accessible from multiple ip's (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~myfolder/myscript.php), pls. tell how to achieve this on a CentOS 5.5 (64bit) install running apache.

I will be calling the script from another PHP script on same server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is achieved with Apache's configs. Most installs default to listening on all bound IPs any way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your server that he listen on 2 ip-addresses.

When you define your vhost you can make *:80 then your server listen to all ips.